# Is this grammatically correct? "More often than not, I work on teams where I share a pool of work with other colleagues"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions

"More often than not, I work on teams where I share a pool of work with other colleagues."

1. Is "where" the correct conjunction?
2. Is it correct to use "teams" (plural) in former part of the sentence and "a pool" (singular) in the latter part?

Comment: *“More often than not I work within teams that share from a pool of work."*

Comment: The sentence as you wrote it is fine. The comma is also fine as you wrote it. For team/teams, pool/pools, with colleague/colleagues, you may choose any combination that is appropriate. E.g. "I work on a team where I share pools of work with another colleague." is also 100% OK (but it implies different semantics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "More often than not, I work on teams wherein I share pools of work with other colleagues."

I don't think many would fault your sentence as written, but I think the switch to the singular in "pool" is a bit ambiguous (presumably the different teams have different pools). I also think "wherein" is a better preposition for "teams," since a team is not a location, but an group one is in, with, or on (but not "at").